# RSS reader in VB 2008?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, rss, rss-reader

Are there any built in libraries/classes in VB 2008 to help to create an RSS reader?

Are there any tutorials online that would help?

Please provide links when answering the second part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) contains a bunch of classes for creating and consuming RSS and Atom feeds.

Edit: I've never used these classes, so I can't give any examples from my own code. However, a quick search turned up some examples that seem pretty good. Sorry they're not in VB, but the important parts (using the Syndication classes) are mostly the same in both languages.

- [Daniel Cazzulino](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2007/11/22/ForgetaboutwritingAtomorRSSXMLhandlingcodeeveragain.aspx)
- [dotnetslackers](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/How-to-create-a-syndication-feed-for-your-website.aspx)
- [Darren Johnstone](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/06/14/using-aspnet-35-to-read-an-rss-feed-asynchronously/)

Comment: Please explain a bit more FTW. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly built in.

RSS documents are XML documents; you do have `XmlDocument` or can XML serialize a class to create that RSS feed.

- [Creating an Online RSS News Aggregator with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478968.aspx)
- [RSS in .NET Made Easy with XML Serialization](http://weblogs.asp.net/skillet/archive/2006/08/29/RSS-in-.NET-Made-Easy-with-XML-Serialization.aspx)