# How can I programmatically get data from a webpage that has html and javascript

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get list of jobs from this website into my program:
https://emploisfp-psjobs.cfp-psc.gc.ca/psrs-srfp/applicant/page2440?fromMenu=true&toggleLanguage=en

The problem is, I only get some HTML tags. How can I get the jobs listed in this webpage using Visual Basic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no real problem defined and the inferred issue relates to screen scraping which may not be allowed under the terms of the site being scraped.

Comment: Is it okay to scrap RSS feeds?

Comment: yes consuming an RSS feed is exactly what they are intended for and is a reliable solution. Have a look at [RSS reader in VB 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044239/rss-reader-in-vb-2008)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to understand how the website works.
What i saw just now, is that it takes a couple of seconds to load the listings.
So you would have to check for that somehow.
Then you can go through the HTML Code and look for the function that redirects you to the page of the job.That could be just an `<a href="...">` or a JavaScript function.

ADDED: You basically have to interpret the HTML, so you get the information you want out of it. Can be worth the effort, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

PS: I have no experience with Visual Basic so i can only give you a train of thought.